# Displaying data in horizontal format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there way to generate data to horizontal table in rails ? please guide me

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <% @products.each do |pr| %>
      <th width="25px"><%= pr.name %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <% @products.each do |pr| %>
      <th width="25px"><%= pr.brand %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

table products on database

```
|  name  | brand  |
-------------------
|   A    | brand1 |
|   B    | brand2 |
|   C    | brand3 |
```

I want to generate on view looks like :

```
|  A     |   B    |   C    |
----------------------------
| brand1 | brand2 | brand3 |
```

Comment: Doesn't your code work?

Comment: No, it's work.. but my question, is there any way other than using my code?

Comment: You mean you want column based model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149485/generating-column-based-table-in-ruby-on-rails-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is to use [transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
<% @products.collect{|p| [p.name, p.brand]}.transpose.each do |line| %>
  <tr>
    <% line.each do |cell| %>
      <td><%= cell %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Explanations:

`@products.collect{|p| [p.name, p.brand]}` will generate the following array:
[ ['A', 'brand1'], ['B', 'brand2'], ['C', 'brand3'] ]

`transpose` will transpose your array like this:
[ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3'] ]

When looping on that array, the first `line` will be your product names, the second `line` will be your brands names.

Careful not to use on very large result set, because `@products.collect` is eager loading

Answer (score 1):

Use collect to build Hash

```
<tr>   
  <% @products.collect{ |p| {name: p.name, brand: p.brand }}.each do |pr| %>
    <th width="25px"><%= pr[:name] %></th>
    <th width="25px"><%= pr[:brand] %></th>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **[each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)**

```
<tr>
    <% Product(1..10).each_slice(3) do |pr| %>
      <th width="25px"><%= pr.name %></th>
      <th width="25px"><%= pr.brand %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

**Note:** Didn't tested it.Just have a try and let me know.

Comment: You can use "in_groups" also

Comment: @SSR Yup :) Just had my first look at that.Thanks!